# My computer turns off unexpectedly when left idle (light to no load)

Tags: windows-10, crash

Every time I leave my computer idling and downloading something, after 20 minutes to an hour, it crashes.

By “crashes,” I mean, that it just shuts off unexpectedly, without blue screen.

I tried opening some apps while leaving it idle (it runs fine when it's not idle) opening multiple desktops which seemed to fix it, even checked if it was overheating (which it wasn't).

So does anyone have a solution to this? That problem is irritating and i couldn't find a solution.

### [image]

Here are my computer specs:

> - Windows 10 Pro 1803 (updated to 1709 some days ago)
> - 2gb of RAM
> - Mobile Intel 4 Series Chipset Family (Total Memory: 1052, VRAM: 64mb, Shared Memory: 988mb)
> - Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5870 @2.00GHz
> - 32-bit operating system, x64-based processor

P.S: I checked for memory problems and found none. And check for disk errors and found none too.

### Edit: I fixed all the "unknown devices" in device manager, freed up space on my pc, cleaned the registry, checking for any viruses.... and nothing, the problem still persist, i beg you to help me this problem is so annoying, i can't leave my pc to download something while im somewhere else, i can't watch a full movie without it shutting off (i mean powers off without warning, no error message no nothing.

I fixed my problem by using another computer.

Comment: Hi, There's not enough information to begin diagnosing this properly. You'll have to check the event viewer for any notable errors/warnings around the time of the crash, and it may be worth Checking the RAM as well.

Comment: oh yes I'm sorry i took a snapshot before but i forgot to post it

Comment: By the way, we're not here to judge you if you have a potato PC: it's a PC and it works (that's all). We're here to assist you with your issue but you need to give us proper info like @Stese said.

Comment: The error highlighted is normal after a powercycle/crash. Look for errors before then, and after you left the machine idle.

Comment: look under details tab for more details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: I actually tried to see what it does before crashing: power was ok and it crashed without warning @Stese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I now use another PC by the way.

So turns out: I used to remove the battery of that PC I was having problems with, while it was on.... I think I might have short-circuited it, I stopped using it for 2 months and tried turning it on again... nothing. It doesn't even charge.

Anyway... I will sell that PC as an antic maybe in 10 year to a collector XD

**PS: How much should i sell it for? How much do anyone think it would be worth in 10 years??**